# How to fix Class Not Found Error when making subsequent connections to AS400 DB2 and zOS DB2 databases?

Tags: python, db2, jaydebeapi

I am a tester. As part of my tests, I have to extract data from two DB2 databases. One resides on z/OS, and the other resides on AS400

When I call the functions sequentially, the second one fails with TypeError: "Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" or  "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" regardless of the order in which function is called.

Could you please help me understand why the jaydebeapi.connect statement in the second statement fails with Class Not Found? Did I forget to close something (I used context manager for the connection)?

Individually, the functions work fine. But when I call one after the other, the second one fails. Please help.

Python Version: 3.7.0
JayDeBeApi==1.2.3
JPype1==1.1.2

Here's the function I wrote to extract data from DB2 database on zOS

```
 def query_zos_db2_database(hostname, port, database, username, password, sql_stmt, output_file_path, delimiter="|", header_flag=True):
    """
    Function to connect to a DB2 database hosted on z/OS Mainframe
    :param hostname:
    :param port:
    :param database:
    :param username:
    :param password:
    :param sql_stmt:
    :param output_file_path:
    :param delimiter:
    :param header_flag:
    :return:
    """

    my_name = "query_zos_db2_database()"
    st = timeit.default_timer()
    print("Entered :{}".format(my_name))
    curr_dir = os.getcwd()
    jar_file_path = "{}/../drivers/db2jcc/db2jcc4.jar".format(curr_dir)
    jar_file_path = os.path.abspath(jar_file_path)
    print(jar_file_path)
    if not os.path.exists(jar_file_path):
        logger.error("File not found: {}".format(jar_file_path))
        exit(1)

    list_credentials = list()
    list_credentials.append(username)
    list_credentials.append(password)
    jdbc_conn_str = "jdbc:db2://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(hostname, port, database)
    print("Before connection isJVMStarted: {}".format(jpype.isJVMStarted()))

    with jaydebeapi.connect('com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver', jdbc_conn_str, list_credentials, jar_file_path) as conn:
        # print(conn)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_stmt)
        print("After connection isJVMStarted: {}".format(jpype.isJVMStarted()))

        if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
            os.remove(output_file_path)
        with codecs.open(output_file_path, 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=delimiter, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            if header_flag is True or header_flag == 'True':
                if sys.version_info.major == 2:
                    column_names = [item[0].encode('utf-8') for item in cursor.description]
                    print(column_names)
                else:
                    column_names = [item[0] for item in cursor.description]
                csvwriter.writerow(column_names)

            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                try:
                    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
                        columns = [unicode(column or '') for column in row]
                    else:
                        columns = [str(column or '') for column in row]

                    out_rec = delimiter.join(columns)
                    fout.write(u"{}\n".format(out_rec))
                except UnicodeEncodeError:
                    print("UnicodeEncodeError- Skipping this record {}".format(row))

    et = timeit.default_timer() - st
    print("Exited: {}; Elapsed Time: {} s".format(my_name, et))
```

Here's the function I write to extract data from DB2 database on AS400:

```
def query_as400_db2_database(hostname, port, database, username, password, sql_stmt, output_file_path, delimiter="|", header_flag=True):
    """
    Function to connect to a DB2 database hosted on AS400 Mainframe
    :param hostname:
    :param port:
    :param database:
    :param username:
    :param password:
    :param sql_stmt:
    :param output_file_path:
    :param delimiter:
    :param header_flag:
    :return:
    """
    my_name = "query_as400_db2_database()"
    st = timeit.default_timer()

    print("Entered: {}".format(my_name))
    curr_dir = os.getcwd()
    jar_file_path = "{}/../drivers/jt400/jt400.jar".format(curr_dir)
    jar_file_path = os.path.abspath(jar_file_path)
    print(jar_file_path)
    if not os.path.exists(jar_file_path):
        logger.error("File not found: {}".format(jar_file_path))
        exit(1)

    list_credentials = list()
    list_credentials.append(username)
    list_credentials.append(password)
    jdbc_conn_str = "jdbc:as400://{};prompt=false;translate binary=true;naming=system".format(hostname)
    print("Before connection isJVMStarted: {}".format(jpype.isJVMStarted()))

    with jaydebeapi.connect('com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver', jdbc_conn_str, list_credentials, jar_file_path) as conn:
        # print(conn)
        print("After connection isJVMStarted: {}".format(jpype.isJVMStarted()))
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql_stmt)

        if os.path.exists(output_file_path):
            os.remove(output_file_path)
        with codecs.open(output_file_path, 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=delimiter, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            if header_flag is True or header_flag == 'True':
                if sys.version_info.major == 2:
                    column_names = [item[0].encode('utf-8') for item in cursor.description]
                    print(column_names)
                else:
                    column_names = [item[0] for item in cursor.description]
                csvwriter.writerow(column_names)

            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                try:
                    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
                        columns = [unicode(column or '') for column in row]
                    else:
                        columns = [str(column or '') for column in row]

                    out_rec = delimiter.join(columns)
                    fout.write(u"{}\n".format(out_rec))
                except UnicodeEncodeError:
                    print("UnicodeEncodeError- Skipping this record {}".format(row))

    et = timeit.default_timer() - st
    print("Exited: {}; Elapsed Time: {} s".format(my_name, et))
```

Comment: Debugging required. Few people on here have concurrent access to both Z/OS and i-series, and also use jaydebeapi with context manager .  I suggest you enable the jdbc trace for both drivers.   Compare the traces of working case to the failing case. Study the trace on the failing path to see details of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

For that particular error case there are two potential error causes.

1- Usually in the Java world the `java.lang.RuntimeException: Class driverClassName not found` exception is raised when we hadn't add the jar file's path to the CLASSPATH environment variable and that's what was exactly attempted to be explained [here](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/blob/cd2fd4c6c047803916fc92a534f02f1213e252d6/jaydebeapi/__init__.py#L232)

2- (the most likely one) It seems like Jaydebeapi doesn't support the establishment of multiple connections for different data sources at the same time.